# RSS to SQL Server, is this possible?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I'd like to store the feed from google newsreader into SQL Server 2012.

Is there any way of doing this? I've been looking around and I cannot find the step by step instruction...

I looked into web service task, but it doesn't look like it will work without WSDL

Comment: Did you read this how to with SSIS?  http://palkotools.blogspot.ca/2011/06/tutorial-how-to-import-rss-feeds-into.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below article would provide some starting point.

[Read an RSS feed from SSIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/02/19/read-an-rss-feed-from-ssis.aspx)

[Consuming an ATOM 1.0 or RSS 2.0 Feed using SSIS](http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/consuming-atom-10-or-rss-20-feed-using.html)

Also [guide provided](http://palkotools.blogspot.ca/2011/06/tutorial-how-to-import-rss-feeds-into.html) by  JiggsJedi in his comment.